# jquery.flash plugin not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, swfobject, internet-explorer-6

I use jquery.flash() plugin to embed flash into my website. The problem is that in IE6 this doesn't work. I tried swfobject (1.5), also, but it gives me (sometimes) some strange errors with n null or something like that, so I decided to use jquery.flash() also. (I use both swfobject and jquery.flash() now)

So, basically, swfobject works but gives me that strange error sometimes (all browsers), so NOT all my flash banners work, and jquery.flash() WORKS in all other browsers, except IE6.

That's frustrating, really.
The website is [infinitdev.ro/medlife/](http://infinitdev.ro/medlife/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Doug, 

I just tried your site in IE6 on my virtual machine and the flash works fine.

Nice site btw :)

Comment: That's strange, at home I have WinXP professional with IE6 by default and all the flash banners from under the header are not working, and at the office I have IE6 in a virtual machine, just like you and they seem to work. Maybe my flash player version from home is too old, but as far as I know, I have at least Flash 9. Don't know what to say in this situation... what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried jQuery version of swfobject? You can grab it from http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/ and it works out of the box. It implements swfobject 2.2 and I use it quite often. Maybe this will help you to embed flash on your website.

Comment: Echo that - swfobject 2.2 is great, works for us flawlessly at http://www.comapping.com